# Image indicator missing in Android Tag

Tags: bug, sponsored-tags

The Android icon was missing for a particular question. But after a few minutes the indicator displayed after a refresh (page reload). Is there any issue?

[image]

Comment: [I blame caching.](http://shouldiblamecaching.com)