# Why is the Android icon not appearing next to the Android tag?

Tags: bug, sponsored-tags

The icon for the [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) tag is not showing up any more. Being used to this feature I find it bit difficult to find more questions of my interest and is becoming difficult to find questions on Stack Overflow's home page.

I have found a similar question [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356811/image-indicator-missing-in-android-tag), but it looks like a different issue. Was there a specific reason behind this change, or is this happening only to me? You can check the attachment for how it looks to me:

[image]

Comment: Maybe Google stopped paying. Or yet another tag sponsor anomaly.

Comment: `favicon` and `favicon-android` is still in the stylesheet, so I'm guessing this is a bug in the redesign of the tag

Comment: Looking from the [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android/info), [tag:android-intent] and [tag:android-activity] should also show the tag sponsor, but it's not shown on the question list either...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I work at Stack Overflow and work directly with Google on all their tag sponsorships.  All three of those tags mentioned are continued to be sponsored by Google in 2019.  We have had a slight delay in organizing the creatives they would like to move forward with but they should be live very shortly.  Google is putting a lot of energy into ensuring the developer community knows that they are actively participating in Stack Overflow and ultimately here as a resource for you.  Their devs are monitoring their product tags and their marketing team is working harder then ever to ensure the text links associated with each tag sponsorship are providing educational technical resources for the community.

Keep an eye out shortly for the logos to return as well as the text links.